# How to find coefficients of linear combination of n numbers, which gives their GCD?

Tags: c++14, greatest-common-divisor

I have an array of numbers and I want their corresponding coefficients such that their linear combination would give me their greatest common divisor.

I found how to do this for 2 numbers in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/) . But I was wondering how to do it efficiently for an array of numbers.

```
ll gcdExtended(ll a, ll b, ll *x, ll *y) 
{ 
    // Base Case 
    if (a == 0) 
    { 
        *x = 0; 
        *y = 1; 
        return b; 
    } 

    ll x1, y1; // To store results of recursive call 
    ll gcd = gcdExtended(b%a, a, &x1, &y1); 

    // Update x and y using results of recursive 
    // call 
    *x = y1 - (b/a) * x1; 
    *y = x1; 

    return gcd; 
}

ll calc(ll gcd, int i)
{
    ll x,y;
    ll gcd_new = gcdExtended(gcd,conc[i],x,y);

    if (i == conc.size()-1)
    {
        return x;
    }
    ll temp = calc(gcd_new, i+1);
    x *= temp;
    y* = temp;

    return x;
}
```

Here is what I tried. `ll` stands for `long long int` and `conc` is a global vector containing the numbers whose GCD needs to be found.

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: @Valentino Please see my edit.

Comment: And why it does not work as expected? Don't let people guess, explain it please.

Comment: I think it'll work iteratively. Find GCD of the first two numbers, then GCD of the first GCD and the next number, and so on. Updating coefficients is left as an exercise for the reader.